# Every terminal is crashing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, terminal, cmd.exe, microsoft

Very weird thing happening: every terminal in my system is crashing after few seconds of opening [cmd, PowerShell, etc.]. I tried with a stand-alone terminal like cmder, that is crashing too.

- It's crashing 4 - 5 seconds after opening it
- Cannot try `sfc /scannow` since it's crashing
- I have checked the Registry and `CommandProcessor` is missing inside `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`

I have tried everything I could find on the internet, any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Try malwarebytes (the free version). Update first, then scan the entire computer.

Comment: You can always run `sfc /scannow` via safe mode or the recovery environment https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/repair-windows-10-using-command-prompt.html

Comment: @Gantendo Sure.. Will try this. Thanks for so quick response. I will update you whether it worked or not.

Comment: @Gantendo Yes the Malwarebytes worked. Thank you so much. I spent days on this. I really want to buy you a coffee.

Comment: No worries bro, we are here to help. Glad it worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has resolved their problem by removing malware from their system